# How would one take a picture at programmed interval -iOS/iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation

Seems like this is an often enough asked question. Rather than asking if possible, I'm wondering if there's any potential workarounds.

I understand [iPhone background tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) will not allow one to take pictures from a Background Task.

Would there be any other solution to **capturing a picture programatically, (1 hr+ intervals**) on iOS?

It appears there a variety of potential solutions on Android:

- Background services (execute camera function from background)
- A wakelock (keeps the App alive at the expense of battery)
- Timer (utilize timer to start a service or app)

What would be a potential solution on iOS, or is there actually NO solution for this. Not being an iPhone user myself, are there not any time lapse apps that have the screen turn off??

Comment: App Store and iOS policies have strict rules about background usage. Since there is no documented workaround, it is unlikely to have an acceptable solution for this.

Comment: Ah I see, so in ios is there an equivalent for waking an app up, OR, keeping an app alive for a purpose such as this?